# Stack push operation in MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

In MIPS Assembly, we can declare stack and can perform push operation in it by using the following simple code:

```
sw $t0,0($sp)
```

My question is: can I use a register in place of  `0` (any alternative?). Because I want to increment in the register and to perform stack operation in a special flow.

Supposed operation is:

```
sw $t0,$s0($sp)

addi $s0,$s0,1
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I'm not MIPS programmer, so I will comment just on principle level. Basically you can, although very likely that addressing mode is invalid, but you can do something like `add $s0,$s0,$sp` at the beginning and then doing that `addi $s0,$s0,4` will move you one word further in memory. And of course `sw $t0,($s0)` to use it. Stack memory is just ordinary memory, there's nothing special about it, except the `$sp` is used to point at "top of stack". But pushing value onto stack usually means the `$sp` is moving down in memory (sub sp,4), so `sw $t0,4($sp)` is overwriting older values, not newer.

Comment: https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/stack.html

Comment: Most iterations of the MIPS architecture do not include register+register indexing, so `sw $t0, $s0($sp)` is usually an assembler syntax error, and not a legal instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's very simple.As

```
la $t0,$sp

loop:

sw $t1,0($sp)
addi $sp,$sp,4


conditon

exit:
```

each time there is updating of $sp register.

Comment: Normally the stack grows *downward* so this is backwards.  IDK the convention on MIPS, but on most ISAs it's normally also a "full" stack, pointing at the last thing pushed.  So `addi $sp, $sp, -4` / `sw $t1, ($sp)` in that order, with an offset of `-4`.